# get longitude/latitude from get_map() zoom level

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggmap

In the code below, is it possible to get longitude/latitude values for a given zoom level of`get_map()?` At this time I can only read off the approximate values from the image of the map itself.

```
suppressMessages(library(ggmap))
ny.map <- get_map(location = geocode("New York"),
                  zoom = 15)
print(ggmap(ny.map))
```

[image]
Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked the function, `bb2bbox ()`? I wonder if this is what you want.

Comment: @jazzuro `bb2bbox(attr(ny.map, 'bb')`is indeed what I need - thanks.

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
attr(ny.map, 'bb')
#     ll.lat    ll.lon   ur.lat    ur.lon
# 1 40.70235 -74.01968 40.72317 -73.99222
```

In which

- ll = "lower left"
- ur = "upper right"
- lat = "latitude"
- lon = "longitude"